# Convert multiple arrays to single JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I need help converting several arrays:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
y = ['d', 'e', 'f']
z = ['d', 'g', 'h']
```

Into a single JSON:

```
{
    a: { b: { c: 'done' }},
    d: { e: { f: 'done' },
         g: { h: 'done' }}
}
```

Is this possible using recursion? I can't seem to get it working properly so I was wondering if there is already an easy way to do this in JS.

Comment: Your transformation seems odd. Is there a specific reason that you are transforming siblings (a, b, c) into children?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var struct = {};
var paths = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d', 'e', 'f'],
    ['d', 'g', 'h']
];

paths.forEach(function (path) {
    var ref;
    ref = struct;
    path.forEach(function (elem, index) {
        if (!ref[elem]) {
            ref[elem] = index === path.length - 1 ? "done": {};
        }
        ref = ref[elem];
    });
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(struct, null, "\t"));
```

Output:

```
{
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "c": "done"
        }
    },
    "d": {
        "e": {
            "f": "done"
        },
        "g": {
            "h": "done"
        }
    }
}
```

Note: this script will fail if your input is like:

```
var paths = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
];
```

It decided `c` should be `"done"` but then there is another level. maybe this wont ever happen, if it does, figure out what you want the result to be.

Comment: Yes, there might be a situation where the paths are different lengths.

Comment: If you drop the `"done"` requirement you should be fine. Change that one line to `ref[elem] = {};`

Answer (score 0):

A version with [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var x = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    y = ['d', 'e', 'f'],
    z = ['d', 'g', 'h'],
    object = function (array) {
        var o = {};
        array.forEach(function (a) {
            var last = a.pop();
            a.reduce(function (r, b) {
                r[b] = r[b] || {};
                return r[b];
            }, o)[last] = 'done';
        });
        return o;
    }([x, y, z]);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```